# how to get the a coarse random signal in the verilog not fine?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Now, I'm trying to make a coarse random signal not fine.
So I'm using the $urandom command in the verilog.
But still I can't  get the coarse random signal.

the below is the my random verilog code but I don't know how to get the  a coarse random signal not fine.

```
always@(clk) begin

temp = $urandom;

end
```

## EDIT

coarse random signal means I can tell you by using adder signal.

```
reg [29:0] temp;

always@(posedge clk or negedge rst) begin
if(!rst)
temp <= 0;
else
temp <= temp + 1;
end
```

From here, we can see temp[0] and temp[29] signals differences what i mean the coarse random signal have a change with enough change period but find random signal means like temp[0] is rapidly changed signal .

Comment: Please explain a coarse random signal.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: Still don't understand. Try finding different words other than "fine" and "coarse" and in terms of probabilities. $urandom returns a number where the probability of each bit changing is independent from other bits, and is 50%

Comment: @dave_59 I think the coarse means not frequently change signal on the clock. and fine means frequently change signal on the clock.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I can think of two ways of doing, both requires using the previous state of temp.

```
randomize(temp) with {foreach (temp[bitt]) temp[bitt] ^ const'(temp[bitt]) dist {1:=1, 0:=10};};
```

The above says for each bit of temp, the probability of a random bit being the same its current state is 10 times more likely than being different.

```
  randomize(temp) with {$countones(temp^const'(temp)) < 10;};
```

The above says the total number of bits that can be different from the current value is less that ten.