# Triangular signal with noise +1, -1 in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, hdl

I am struggling for some time already and I can't find a simple and useful solution.

I would like to simulate triangular signal in size of 16 bits

[image: signal]

and add a random noise to it with values 1 , 0, -1. It is important that signal with noise never differs for more than 1 from original noise and from previous value in noised signal.
For example, I would like values in that way:

ORIGINAL SIGNAL: 11111  22222  33333  44444  55555 ...

NOISED SIGNAL : 12321  12332  23434  34345  45665 ...

I simulated signal for values between 0 and 30766 because main focus now is adding noise to this original signal. This code work properly because I removed the conditions which limit the difference between values for maximum 1.

This signal is used for test bench.

```
reg [15:0] SIGNAL_i;
reg [15:0] SIGNAL_ii;
reg [15:0] SIGNAL_noise_i;
reg [15:0] SIGNAL_noise_reg; //za hranjenje zasumljenega signala
int RANDOM_noise_i; 
int COUNT_end;
int COUNT;

initial SIGNAL_i=1;
initial COUNT_end=0;
initial COUNT=3'd4; 
initial SIGNAL_ii=0;
initial SIGNAL_noise_i=1;
initial SIGNAL_noise_reg=0;
initial RANDOM_noise_i=1;

initial CLK = 1;

always #5 CLK = ~CLK;

always #10      
begin
SIGNAL_noise_reg <= SIGNAL_noise_i;
RANDOM_noise_i = $signed($urandom_range(0,2))-1;  //random noise generation

//upcount
if ((SIGNAL_i<16'd30766) && (SIGNAL_ii<SIGNAL_i)) //32765
  begin
      begin
        if (COUNT_end==COUNT)
          begin
            assign SIGNAL_noise_i=SIGNAL_i + (RANDOM_noise_i);  
            SIGNAL_i=SIGNAL_i + 1;
            SIGNAL_ii=SIGNAL_ii + 1;
            COUNT_end=0;
            COUNT_end=0;
          end
        else
          begin
            assign SIGNAL_noise_i=SIGNAL_i + (RANDOM_noise_i);  
            COUNT_end= COUNT_end + 1;
          end
      end
  end


//counter on zero  
else if (SIGNAL_i == 0)
  begin
    SIGNAL_i = 1;
    SIGNAL_ii = 0;
    SIGNAL_noise_i = SIGNAL_i + RANDOM_noise_i; 
  end

//down count  
   else
      begin
        if (COUNT_end==COUNT)
          begin
            assign SIGNAL_noise_i=SIGNAL_i + (RANDOM_noise_i);  
            SIGNAL_i=SIGNAL_i - 1;
            SIGNAL_ii=SIGNAL_ii + 1;
            COUNT_end=0;
            COUNT_end=0;
          end
        else
          begin
            assign SIGNAL_noise_i=SIGNAL_i + (RANDOM_noise_i);  
            COUNT_end= COUNT_end + 1;
          end
      end
  end
end
```

I would really appreciate your help!
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the a coarse random signal in the verilog not fine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197205/how-to-get-the-a-coarse-random-signal-in-the-verilog-not-fine)

Comment: I think your question is how to generate a random sequence with only +1,0 and -1 values? What type of distribution did you want?

Comment: I want to have a Triangle Waveform, that goes from 0 till 65,534 and then back again to zero and it is continues. Each value is repeated 4 times. When this is successfuly done I want to add noise to this values as I have given example in my question:

ORIGINAL SIGNAL: 11111 22222 33333 44444 55555 ...

NOISED SIGNAL : 12321 12332 23434 34345 45665 ...

I want to generate this kind of noised signal for one simulation

Answer (score 0):

I got the signal I wanted but for sure there are also beter ways to implement it. I simplified it a bit.

```
  always #10      
  begin
  SIGNAL_noise_reg <= SIGNAL_noise_i;
  RANDOM_noise_i = $signed($urandom_range(0,2))-1; 

    if ((SIGNAL_i<16'd30766) && (SIGNAL_ii<SIGNAL_i)) //32765
    begin

      if(COUNT_end==COUNT-1) 
      begin
        assign SIGNAL_noise_i=SIGNAL_i-1;  
        SIGNAL_i=SIGNAL_i + 1;
        SIGNAL_ii=SIGNAL_ii + 1;
        COUNT_end=0;
      end

      else if (COUNT_end == 0)
      begin
        assign SIGNAL_noise_i=SIGNAL_i -1;  
        COUNT_end= COUNT_end + 1;
      end

      else
      begin
        if (SIGNAL_i + RANDOM_noise_i - SIGNAL_noise_i > 1)
        begin
          assign SIGNAL_noise_i=SIGNAL_i;
          COUNT_end= COUNT_end + 1;
        end
        else
        begin       
          assign SIGNAL_noise_i=SIGNAL_i + RANDOM_noise_i;
          COUNT_end= COUNT_end + 1;
        end
      end
    end

    else if (SIGNAL_i == 0)
    begin
      SIGNAL_i = 1;
      SIGNAL_ii = 0;
      SIGNAL_noise_i = SIGNAL_i + RANDOM_noise_i; 
    end

    else    
    begin

     if(COUNT_end==COUNT-1) 
     begin
       assign SIGNAL_noise_i=SIGNAL_i+1;  
       SIGNAL_i=SIGNAL_i - 1;
       SIGNAL_ii=SIGNAL_ii + 1;
       COUNT_end=0;
     end

     else if (COUNT_end == COUNT-2)
     begin
       assign SIGNAL_noise_i=SIGNAL_i;  
       COUNT_end= COUNT_end + 1;
     end

     else
     begin
       if (SIGNAL_i + RANDOM_noise_i - SIGNAL_noise_i > 1)
       begin
         assign SIGNAL_noise_i=SIGNAL_i;
         COUNT_end= COUNT_end + 1;
       end
       else
       begin       
         assign SIGNAL_noise_i=SIGNAL_i + RANDOM_noise_i;
         COUNT_end= COUNT_end + 1;
       end
     end
    end
  end
```